# NetBeans 12.0 LTS - Hibernate Plugin require Freemarker Integration implementation version 238

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

In `Apache NetBeans 12.0 LTS`

When I'm trying to install `Hibernate plugin` it says :

> **Some plugins require plugin Freemarker Integration to be installed**
>
> **The plugin Freemarker Integration is requested in implementation version 238.
>
>   The following plugin is affected:**
>
> **`Hibernate`**

But there's on [Apache NetBeans Plugin Portal](https://netbeans-vm.apache.org/pluginportal/?search=freemarker&nbv=&cat=) `Freemarker plugin` is not available.

I tried installing Freemarker plugin from old plugin portal of NetBeans

[FreeMarker support for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58284/freemarker-support-for-netbeans)

but getting same error.

I'm using:

```
Debain 10.4 Buster LXQt AMD 64-bits  
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14 LTS
Apache NetBeans 12.0 LTS
```

I've also created issue there at `Apache's JIRA issue tracker`
[No dependent plugins are available at Apache NetBeans plugin portal for Hibernate](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468)

But I think they will not pay attention.

Comment: For those who are here looking for solution, The issue created by @Hemlata at `Apache's JIRA issue tracker` has working solutions now, Please do check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468

Comment: @Hemlata, Were you able to fix this issue. Please help me. I'm in the same position.

Comment: @Rasheek, I read the whole ticket and comments. The links mentioned in the solution is longer there. The link is broken. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

This causes because there is a conflict for the version of freemarker, netbeans is looking for freemarker.jar with OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version: 238, but in my case the OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version: was 239 and that was causing the issue.

You can fix this by

1. Close your running netbeans application
2. Download freemarker.jar with OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version: 238 [org-netbeans-libs-freemarker-RELEASE81.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17AyvRLdWKGyF48LdAvTup41XDLzsexXM/view?usp=sharing) and rename the downloaded library to `org-netbeans-libs-freemarker.jar`
3. Navigate to ide/modules subfolder in  apache netbeans installation directory
4. You will find the freemarker library `org-netbeans-libs-freemarker.jar`, replace this with your downloaded library.
5. Restart the netbeans(or perhaps restarting the computer should work) and you should be able to download the hibernate plugin

ps- you can check the OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version by opening the jar library as an archive and inside the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file

Also refer [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4468) for more information

Comment: I had fixed using this but later NetBeans was not working. But I'd try. Worth using NetBeans 12 it's faster than 11.

Comment: Mohamed Thank you.

Comment: This is working fine for me, I tried it in Mac and now i can install hibernate

Comment: That's great I would try out.

Comment: Also would you tell me it's performance against NB 11.0 LTS?

Comment: @RasheekMohamed, I'm also facing the same issues. the download link you provided is not working. Please help.

Comment: Hi @Tanzeel, The library has been removed, I have uploaded it in my google drive, you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17AyvRLdWKGyF48LdAvTup41XDLzsexXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This answer didn't work on NB 15, any clue of how to solve this issue?

Comment: @AhmadAlshaib [1] I tried this solution on NetBeans 15 as well, and it didn't work for me either (although it did work with NB 12). [2] I noticed that someone added a comment to the bug report linked in the answer above, stating that it also doesn't work with NetBeans 14 either. I'm wondering whether NetBeans even supports Hibernate at present, since such a convoluted hack to get it working is ridiculous. [3] FYI, also see [Install Hibernate in Netbeans 15.0 "version 238"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74082278/install-hibernate-in-netbeans-15-0-version-238), though it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the way.**

1. unistall netbeans.
2. install netbeans (**but not started it yet**)
3. Open: "netbeans-12.0/netbeans/ide/modules/org-netbeans-libs-
   freemarker.jar" with an arquive manager and go to META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
4. change the value 239 for 238 in lines. To be like this:

   OpenIDE-Module-Implementation-Version: 238
   OpenIDE-Module-Specification-Version: 2.42.0.238
5. close and update you change.
6. start the netbeans for the fist time and all will go well.

Comment: When I create new project, wizard won't finish. I re-installed many times but it's same

Answer (score 1):

The **hibernate** plugin was not anything important. I was trying to install that one, but because of the above error, `Netbeans` did not load, and on top of it, the **CentOS-8-Stream** came to logged-out.

So, I remove the hibernate instances.

1. `cd ~/.netbeans/13/`
2. `grep -r "hibernate"`

**Resolution:** Removal of the faulty plugins

Removed the `JAR` s from  `/home/jacobd/netbeans-13/netbeans/java/modules/locale/`

Removed the `XML` s from `/home/jacobd/netbeans-13/netbeans/java/config/Modules` name matching hibernate, two xml will be here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with NetBeans version 16 and solved it by installing `freemaker.jar`  module which replaced the default module that comes with NetBeans.
Please try the following

step 1: Download freemaker modules from the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AySqHHh73y1SDXU9H0wqGtu4VqMWYfRi/view?usp=sharing

step 2:
Close all NetBeans running applications and
copy the downloaded module and go to the NetBeans installation directory as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans-16\netbeans\ide\modules
```

first delete the `org-netbeans-libs-freemar.jar`  and paste the downloaded module to replace `org-netbeans-libs-freemar.jar` that comes with NetBeans ( I mean the one you deleted)

Start NetBeans and go to `Tools > Plugins >Available Plugins`  then scroll until you see Hibernate

This is my screenshot of my installation on windows 10
[image: how to install freemaker.jar and Hibernate in NetBeans]